# Get Data From Nested JSON using React-Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I have a nested json that looks like this but actually 46 brand 840 model and 6300 total years row. I want to get data from that JSON file. And i will create 4 js file. One of them will hold level0 data. other one will hold level1 data. I looked for but examples get that data from URL so how to get data from nested json level by level ?

```
{"Acura": 
    {"CL": 
        {"2003.0": 
            {"AC heater": [0.0], "Average Milage of AC heater": [0.0]
            }
        }
        {"2002.0"
            {"AC heater": [0.0], "Average Milage of AC heater": [0.0]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what that JSON is showing, but I am pretty sure the "CL" is a category or something. So the CL should not be an object instead it should be an array.

Comment: Acura is car brand ,CL is Acura model, 2003 is the version of Acura CL and finally its car errors. My JSON goes like Acura CL then Acura CLX ... when all models for that brand ends it starts with another brand like  Audi 100 Audi 200 etc. I will just make an easy mobile app with four page that shows car errors

Answer (score 0):

This way you can easily filter by brand or any key-value you want. You can also loop over each car model. This is a way to structure it instead of just using objects. Look up arrays and use those instead

```
    {"cars": {
      "lambogrhini" : [
        {"model" :"Aventador", "mile":1000, errors : [{"year":2010,"error":0},{"year":2011,"error":12}] }
      ],
      "ferrari" : [
        {"model" :"enzo", "mile":200,errors : [{"year":2010,"error":0},{"year":2011,"error":12}]}
      ],
      "tesla" : [
        {"model" :"model x", "mile":10,errors : [{"year":2010,"error":0},{"year":2011,"error":12}]}
      ] 
     }  
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.But can you show me if I add year how will it look as well ? Because my data is not just lamborgini Aventador miles errors its like "Lamborghini->Aventador->2010->errors // Lamborghini->Aventador->2011->errors "

Comment: added an updated answer, but you should look into how to structure your data and learn

Comment: I understand this make sense now. What does "[ ]" mean after "errors :" ?